# Python: 2.4 Format String Not Working

Tags: python

My original 2.7 code is here:

```
            myFile = open(prjFile, 'w+')
            myFile.write("""<VirtualHost 192.168.75.100:80>
    ServerName www.{hostName}
    ServerAlias {hostNameshort}.* www.{hostNameshort}.*
    DocumentRoot {prjDir}/html
    CustomLog \\|/usr/sbin/cronolog /var/log/httpd/class/{prjCode}/\{hostName}.log.%Y%m%d\" urchin"
</VirtualHost>""".format(hostName=hostName, hostNameshort=hostNameshort, prjDir=prjDir, prjCode=prjCode))
            myFile.close()
```

And I am trying to make it 2.4 compatible by doing this:

```
myFile = open(prjFile, 'w+')
myFile.write("""<VirtualHost 192.168.75.100:80>
    ServerName www.%(hostName)s
    ServerAlias %(hostNameshort).* www.%(hostNameshort)s.*
    DocumentRoot %(prjDir)s/html
    CustomLog \\|/usr/sbin/cronolog /var/log/httpd/class/prjCode}/\%(hostName)s.log.%Y%m%d\" urchin"
</VirtualHost>""" % ('hostName', 'hostNameshort', 'prjDir', 'prjCode'))
myFile.close()
```

But my error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testfunction.py", line 20, in <module>
    </VirtualHost>""" % ('hostName', 'hostNameshort', 'prjDir', 'prjCode'))
TypeError: format requires a mapping
```

I have searched for answers here and nothing I am trying seems to work. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error tells it all, you're passing a `tuple` to `__mod__` when it requires a mapping (`dict`).  e.g. you want something like:

```
print """<VirtualHost 192.168.75.100:80>
    ServerName www.%(hostName)s
    ServerAlias %(hostNameshort)s.* www.%(hostNameshort)s.*
    DocumentRoot %(prjDir)s/html
    CustomLog \\|/usr/sbin/cronolog /var/log/httpd/class/prjCode}/\%(hostName)s.log.%%Y%%m%%d\" urchin"
</VirtualHost>""" % dict(hostName='foo',hostNameshort='bar',prjDir='baz')
```

There were a few other things I needed to do.  I needed to add an `s` on this line:

```
ServerAlias %(hostNameshort).* www.%(hostNameshort)s.*
```

And I needed to double the `%` in the last line to escape the percent signs in `'%Y%m%d'`

Comment: Ah thank you! And that will pass the pre-defined variables to it?

Comment: `dict` isn't working that way! you should use: `dict(key=value)`

Comment: @JacobColeman -- you were missing an `s` after one of your `%(name)s` substitution strings.

Comment: @JacobColeman -- Sorry I didn't look at your original quite close enough to get it right on the first try :)

Answer (score 1):

you can remove the names from the format strings, like `%(hostNameshort)s` to `%s` or feed that data as a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the names of the string and replace them for "%s" and then map each variable to it (repeating when necessary). In addition remove or change the part

> ".log.%Y%m%d\"

because it is also trying to be mapped and it does not find the corresponding values

Comment: How else am I going to have it spit out a timestamp for the log then?

Comment: That did fix the previous tracebacks, but I would like to be able to pass a timestamp in shell to the log.

Comment: Use %%Y%%m%%d instead of %Y%m%d

Comment: Hi Jacob in order to do that, I suggest you to first convert the timestamp to a string (by using strftime() ) and then pass this with another %s. It's a two-step process but it should work well.